# SetState com onChange, ReactJs

Tags: react

eu trouxe um probleminha que estou passando em uma aplicação que estou fazendo no React, irei replicar logo aqui abaixo.

**STATE DECLARADO NO COMPONENTE**

```
this.state = { estadoCivil: ''};
```

**JS**

```
onChange = e => {this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});
console.log(this.state);
```

**JSX**

```
 <div className="form-group col-12">
                <label>Estado Civil</label>
                    <select id="estado-civil" className="custom-select" name="estadoCivil"
                     onChange={this.onChange} required >
                        <option defaultValue>selecione uma opção</option>
                        <option value='solteiro'>Solteiro(a)</option>
                        <option value='casado'>Casado(a)</option>
                        <option value='viuvo'>Viúvo(a)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Pessoal, eis aí a minha dúvida, a solução acima funciona, mas sempre que altero o valor no select e executa a função onChange, ela retorna no console o estadoCivil no estado anterior, o setState parece sempre estar atrasado, nunca mostra o valor que altero no momento. Alguém poderia ajudar? Desde já, meu muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Não se deve confiar na "syncronidade" do `setState` no React, para mostrar no console, você deveria fazer algo do tipo:

```
onChange = e => {
  this.setState(
    {[e.target.name]: e.target.value},
    () => console.log(this.state)); //coloca o console no callback do `setState`
}
```

[React state e seu callback](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Este callback do `setState` é chamado quando a função é terminada.

Comment: Depois de observar mais um pouco e dar uma olhada na documentação, realmente percebi que o meu erro foi mais por falta de atenção, muito obrigado pela ajuda.