# O setState não está funcionando

Tags: api, react

Eu já vi vários post sobre isso, mas nenhum até agr me ajudou muito...

Quando dá o console.log(this.state.lista); o resulato é indefinido... sendo que eu tenho certeza que os dados estão chegando da API.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
  super(props)
    this.state = {
       lista: []
    }
}

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://api.api-futebol.com.br/v1/campeonatos/10/tabela";
    return fetch(url, {
      headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: "Bearer test_34g2irhefu2h2rf92hr"
      })
      
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          lista: response.lista
        }),
        console.log(this.state.lista);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      });
    
  }
render() {
    return (<div>
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          />
          <Table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th />
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>P</th>
                <th>J</th>
                <th>V</th>
                <th>E</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>Recentes</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.lista && this.state.lista.map(infos => {
                return (
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <img src={infos.time.escudo} style={{ width: "28px" }} />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <font
                        color={this.posicao(infos.posicao, this.teste.length)}
                      >
                        {infos.time.nome_popular}
                      </font>
                    </td>
                    <td>{infos.pontos}</td>
                    <td>{infos.jogos}</td>
                    <td>{infos.vitorias}</td>
                    <td>{infos.empates}</td>
                    <td>{infos.derrotas}</td>
                    <td>
                      {this.recente(infos.ultimos_jogos[0])}
                      {this.recente(infos.ultimos_jogos[1])}
                      {this.recente(infos.ultimos_jogos[2])}
                      {this.recente(infos.ultimos_jogos[3])}
                      {this.recente(infos.ultimos_jogos[4])}
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      </>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [State retornando valor errado / atrasado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484875/state-retornando-valor-errado-atrasado)

Comment: Também tem essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369728/setstate-com-onchange-reactjs

Answer (score 1):

O setState é assíncrono... quando invocas `this.setState(...` a mudança não é imediata. Esse é o paradigma de React, nunca assumas que é imediato (assíncrono). Prepara o código para valores "vazios" para depois mudarem quando os valores "chegarem".

O `setState`, permite um segundo argumento: uma callback, que corre **depois** do estado ter mudado. Aí sim podes colocar esse `console.log`.

Testa este código, e reflete sobre como funciona tendo em conta o que escrevi aqui:

```
console.log('A', resposta.lista.length); // preenchido
this.setState({
  lista: response.lista
}, () => console.log('B', this.state.lista.length)) // preenchido
console.log('C', this.state.lista.length); // vazio
```

Comment: aah vlw, agora entendi. Era isso mesmo

Comment: @Miho ótimo. Se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite :)